# CSS3DObject is Always in Front of WebGL Mesh

Tags: html, three.js, 3d, transform

I am mixing the `CSS3D Renderer` with `WebGL Renderer` to add `HTML` elements in 3D space to a `WebGL` scene. The `CSS3DObject` is in front of `WebGL` Meshes even though the `WebGL Renderer` has a higher z-index.

Here is the jsfiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/kd9Tc/**

This is what the scene looks like. Note the back view.[image]

Whenever the `CSS3DObject` hits a mesh, I would like the correct depth to be displayed. I believe that this has something to do with the `z-buffer` or `depth`. I would prefer to have the text on a transparent background and not a solid color as shown in the example.

How can this be done?

Comment: The `CSS3Renderer` does not have a depth buffer, nor does it know anything about the `WebGLRenderer` depth buffer. Why not use WebGL only, and use Sprites for the text? Experiment first, to make sure it is satisfactory for your needs.

Comment: @WestLangley Can text Sprites move in 3D space along with a Mesh? I'm looking for a way of displaying paragraphs of text on a Mesh of a monitor. Are there any examples of Sprites being used this way?

Comment: Yes, Sprites can exist in 3D -- or use planes. Experiment. http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_ubiquity_test2

Comment: I want an answer for your question. your fiddle explains my problem but the answer doesn't solve it. it's a different scenario